# Ubuntu 18.04 Stuck at Shutdown/Reboot. Possible issue with graphics card

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, 18.04, amd-graphics

I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04. Since then it always gets stuck on shutdown or rebooting while running through some commands. As a result, I have to do a hard reboot by pressing the power button. I have dual boot with Windows 10 with secure boot disabled. 
When I boot to Ubuntu again, it gets stuck sometimes before login screen with a black screen or after login screen with a purple blank screen but I can login to `tty`. 
Though it boots well if I run `dpkg` from the `GRUB` menu each time. 
Even when I can log in, there is no brightness control working. Many times, Ubuntu fails to identify the lan connection. 
How could I fix the shutdown problem? 
System info:

`Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz
Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
AMD radeon R7 M440
Ubuntu 18.04, kernel: 4.15.0-22-generic`

Answer (score 1):

I got the very simimlar issue. After a new installation of ubuntu 18.04.2 on my laptop, **everytime when I try to restart or shutdown the system, it stucks on the shutdown screen with a Ubuntu log** like the following screen and I have to press power button to shutdown:

[image]

And I solved the problem by **switch from Nouveau driver to NVIDIA driver**, using Software & Updates App, as following screenshot. The problem disappers after using NVIDIA driver, so I guess there are some potential bugs in Nouveau driver.

[image]

---

And here is my video cards info (the laptop have two video cards, one Intel integrated video card and one NVIDIA card):

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
# OR
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX150]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

---

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001D12sv00001D72sd00001604bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Answer (score 1):

Another dumb solution for Ubuntu 18.04 reboot stuck: 
I had an American Megatrends BIOS.
Once I changed the OS Selection from Windows 7 to Windows 8.X
the problem disappeared.

Comment: I don't get how this is a solution to the stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 'stuck at shutdown/reboot' But I found a workaround.

How about trying old linux-kernels ? --- for example, v4.0-vivid, v4.1-wily ~ v4.5-wily

1. Install ukuu:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ukuu
   ```
2. Check the list of available kernels:

   ```
   sudo ukuu --list
   ```
3. install old kernels:

   ```
   sudo ukuu --install v4.5-wily
   ```
4. Remove current kernel:

   reboot by advanced mode and choose old kernel.open terminal.

   ```
   sudo ukuu --remove (current kernel)
   ```

Comment: I did not try going back to this long, but I tried a few kernels which were there by default, 4.15.20 and 4.15.18 iirc. That had not helped. But now I have reinstalled Ubuntu overwriting the previous version.